# Remote connection to iMac with resolution and session problem

Tags: mac, imac, windows, remote-desktop

I have an iMac 27" and when I am not at home, I want to be remotely connected to it using a Lenovo with a 13" screen. I faced two problems with the classic VNC connection:

1. The first problem is that I cannot connect into my session which already opened. The remote connection opens a new session even if a session is opened on the Mac and I have no access to the program which I have let opened on the already open (on the Mac) session.
2. The second problem relates to the screen resolution. Because of the 27" to 13", I cannot have the complete view on the windows. I am looking for a way to adapt the resolution of the remote connection to view the complete iMac desktop on my 13" PC.

Do you have any idea on how to resolve both problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete VNC viewer have option on the screen scale. I used the google VNC which haven't the option.
If you have same pb, you can dl it at https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewe